# PII violation emails even while its being fixed and shows no PII in reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, pii

I used customTask in Universal Analytics tags via tag Manager to tackle PII. After that, I regularly monitored reports in Google Analytics and found all the hits were cleaned.(i.e. PII redacted)

But I still get emails from adwords-noreply@google.com, that some of the URLs  linked to particular 'remarketing lists' are violating PII.

Now there's no way to confirm that PII is actually violated. I dont know where I am supposed to look, in which section (of Adwords account or Analytics account) can I see the URLs being passing PII info to Google?

This is what I'm seeing in GA reports:

https://siteurl/u/password-reset/reset?email=ja[ REDACTED EMAIL]l.com&authenticationCode=8127489044212

this is what is sent in the violation email:

https://siteurl/u/password-reset/reset?email=jack@emabell.com&authenticationCode=8127489044212

If I have redacted the PII using tag manager, do I still need to do something in the Adwords account ?

Comment: If the notification is from adwords the problems is not in Google Analytics. Remember that adwords tags are being fired too on those URLs and storing the email. You need to reformat your site so it doesnt store PII on the URL or at least hash it first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. Yes I found out that eventually that some Adwords remarketing tags were being fired too

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that custom fields cannot be added with tag type- 'AdWords Remarketing', due to which I couldn't run my redacting logic using 'customTask'.

Hence I created a customHTML tag and fired it on the 'Page View' event which filtered all the URLs

Answer (score 0):

PII in GA is of a serious concept. Eventually, Google might delete your data.
I usually solve this by using filters in GA View. This is like a last line of defence

Guide on how to setup is here
https://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/google-analytics-pii-safe-guarding-emails-2/